# Deleting records that are over 4 years old from today's date on MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, intervals, rowdeleting

I want to delete records from my table when an end-date column is over 3 years expired past the current date

See below for what i have already tried

```
DELETE FROM membership
WHERE (SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM end_date)) <
(SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL -4 YEAR))))
```

I expect results that are from 2016 and before that to be deleted in my table

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE End_Date < Date_Add(curdate(),Interval -4 Year)`  Delete all records 4 years prior to today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete everything that has an end_date with a year of 2016 or older:

```
DELETE FROM membership WHERE YEAR(end_date) <= YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
```

EDIT: If you want to delete everything with an end_date that is over 3 years old:

```
DELETE FROM membership WHERE end_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR;
```

Comment: @Gary Mannion: Glad to help!

Comment: Just a side note; if there is **a lot** of data, and the year is what matters; it would probably better to use `end_date <= (calculated last day or datetime of desired year)`. If you have an index on end_date, YEAR(end_date) would prevent MySQL from taking advantage of it.

Comment: I did not think of that. That could be easily acheived by doing this: `DELETE FROM membership WHERE end_date < CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR), '-01-01');`

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- compare the bare column `end_date` against a value, as a date type
- test expressions in SELECT statements, before running DELETE

What is the first date value that is greater than the end_date on the rows you want to delete?  Test that expression in a SELECT statement.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y-01-01') + INTERVAL -3 YEAR
```

returns

```
2016-01-01
```

or, date value four years before now

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -4 YEAR
```

returns:

```
2015-04-05
```

adjust that expression until it returns the value we need. Then we can include that expression in a statement, comparing to bare column `end_date` column, like this:

```
SELECT m.* 
  FROM membership m 
 WHERE m.end_date < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -4 YEAR
 ORDER BY m.end_date DESC
```

or if we know that the date value we need is `'2015-04-05'` or `'2017-01-01'` then we can just specify that as a literal:

```
SELECT m.* 
  FROM membership m 
 WHERE m.end_date < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
 ORDER BY m.end_date DESC
```

---

After we confirm that the SELECT statement is returning the set of rows we want to delete, then we can replace the `SELECT` keyword with `DELETE`.